# How properly work with LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have generated such `xml` file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Requestes>
  <Single_Request num="1">
    <numRequest>212</numRequest>
    <IDWork>12</IDWork>
    <NumObject>21</NumObject>
    <lvlPriority>2</lvlPriority>
    <NumIn1Period>21</NumIn1Period>
  </Single_Request>
</Requestes>
```

My aim is to get `IDWork`,`numRequest` and etc elements. I tried to get them this way:

```
foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
  {
   if (el.Name == "Single_Request") 
       {
          string num = el.Elements("numRequest").Value;  
// but he says, that he cant do this  .Value because it doest exist at all  
       }          
    }
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Instead of looping through the whole xml-file you could use Descendants method to get all nodes of a certain kind: `doc.Root.Descendants("Single_Request")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this error, because `Elements("numRequest")` returns collection of elements, not single element. You should use `Element("numRequest")` instead.

Also I suggest you to use query for getting elements by name instead of enumerating all elements and verifying their names:

```
var request = doc.Root.Element("Single_Request");
var num = (int)request.Element("numRequest");
```

Usually you use anonymous types or custom objects to group values parsed from xml:

```
var query = from r in doc.Root.Elements("Single_Request")
            where (int)r.Attribute("num") == 1 // condition
            select new {
                NumRequest = (int)request.Element("numRequest"),
                IdWork = (int)request.Element("IDWork"),
                NumObject = (int)request.Element("NumObject")
            };

var request = query.SinlgleOrDefault();
// use request.IdWork
```

Comment: Oh thank you, now it works )) Just I need to figure out how to cast from `string` to `int` ))

Comment: @Rocketq just cast element to `int` instead of reading its `Value`. LINQ to XML will parse value and return integer value for you

Comment: Appreciate  for help @lazyberezovsky now it works, as should.